# every element of A is equal to its co-factor

Tags: matrices

If $AA^T = I$ and $\det(A) = 1$,

then my doubt is this: how can we prove every element of $A$ is equal to its co-factor?

Comment: What's a co-factor?

Answer (score 4):

$AA^T = I \Rightarrow A^T = A^{-1}$

$A^{-1} = \frac{1}{\det{A}}.C^T = C^T$ since $\det{A}=1$

$A.C^T= I \Rightarrow A = (C^T)^T \Rightarrow A= C$

Comment: It should be adjoint A

Comment: The transpose of the cofactor matrix is the adjoint/adjugate matrix

Answer (score 1):

$A^t = A^{-1} = \frac{1}{\det A}(\operatorname{cofactor}(A))^t\quad$
 implies $\quad A = \operatorname{cofactor}(A)\quad$ only if $\quad\det A=1$

The condition $\det A = 1$ is needed, since the determinant appears on the inverse matrix formula. For a general real orthogonal matrix you would get

$A = \frac{1}{\det A}\operatorname{cofactor}(A)$

so each element would be proportional to its cofactor, with $\frac{1}{\det A}$ being the ratio.

Comment: Its not cofactor  . It is adjoint

Comment: $A^{-1} \ne A^t$. Because, $AA^t=I$, but it is not given that $A^tA=I$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix Determinant is 1, then we assume that is orthogonal and left/right multiplication gives you the $I$

Comment: ah I see. It's because that the determinant is non-zero, so we can say that $A^{-1}$ exists, and so $A^{-1} = A^t$.